# What does $\nabla$ mean in the definition of div $\mathbf{F}$

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm slightly confused about what $\nabla$ means, and especially what the dot product means, in the context of the definition of $\text{div} \mathbf{F}$.

For example, you will see Folland in his Advanced Calculus textbook define $\text{div} \mathbf{F} = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} = \partial_1F_1 + \ldots + \partial_n F_n$.

Since $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector field, it's clear we can write $\mathbf{F} = (F_1, \ldots, F_n)$. This is an $n$ dimensional vector where each component $F_i$ is from the vector space of all real valued functions whose domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$. This part makes sense to me.

The gradient for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined as $\nabla f = (\partial_1 f, \ldots, \partial_n f)$. Where I am lost is, what $\nabla$ means without the $f$.

**Question 1:**
If it means $(\partial_1 , \ldots, \partial_n )$, then what space is each element $\partial_i$ from? Furthermore, what is the meaning of $\partial_i$ if it is not next to a $f$?

**My Guess:** My guess is that $\partial_i : (\mathbb{R}^n)^* \rightarrow  (\mathbb{R}^n)^*$, since it takes a real-valued function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and spits out another one (namely its partial derivative).

**Question2:**
But if my guess is correct in Question 1, how does one take a dot product of $\nabla$ and $\mathbf{F}$ if they're not from the same space? ($F_i$ is from the vector space of all real valued functions whose domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$, where as $\partial_i$ is not.)

Comment: This notation is pretty common in physics, and as such similar questions have appeared on Physics.SE. In particular see this Q&A: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/285697/55641. The upshot is that the notation $\nabla =(\partial_1 , \partial_2,\partial_3)$ is largely just a convenient mnemonic for how the gradient, divergence, and Laplacian operators act in Cartesian coordinates. (There's also the 3D curl operator but it doesn't generalize to arbitrary definitions.)